# Finding a solution for $\sin(x) = \frac{1}{10}(x^2-4\pi x)$

Tags: trigonometry, solution-verification, quadratics

I have been trying to solve this equation but for some reason I can't seem to find a solution. I know the only two solutions are $x=0$ and $x=4\pi$, but I can only find these values graphically. Can someone please explain if it is possible to find this mathematically and help me solve it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read the title.

Comment: @TheLlamaMan: **Hint:** Factor out an $x$ on the RHS and find the two values and see if they satisfy the LHS.

Comment: Factorizing the RHS makes both of those roots obvious. To prove $\Bbb R$ has no others, identify where the RHS is of modulus $\le1$, then consider the behaviour of both sides therein.

Comment: @J.G sorry I am still relatively new to MSE, thanks for the advice

Comment: @Moo thanks for that advice I thinks that's the solution, I don't know why I didn't think of that, so thank you.

Comment: Note: the factorization on the right side works for getting simple solutons only because the "amplitude" of the sine function is small enough.  The equation $ \ 1.5 \sin x \ = \ \frac{1}{10} (x^2 - 4\pi x) \ $ has _four_ roots, two of which would need to be approximated.  So keep in mind that this is not a _general_ approach.